# Buttons look wrong on Qt6.5 Linux (OK on 6.4)

Tags: linux, qt, qt6

Since installing Qt 6.5.0 on a fresh installation of Linux Mint Vera (21.1), my buttons and some backgrounds look wrong. They look fine on Qt <= 6.4.3.

Here is a picture of a small section, with 6.4 looks on the left and 6.5 on the right:

[image: Button looks. v6.4 and v6.5]

It also looks wrong on a minimal form, with two buttons, made with Designer. One button enabled and one disabled.

How may I get them back to 6.4 looks?